# How to get vimrc colours to fill the screen?

Tags: bash, vim, colors, vimrc, xterm

I have a colour scheme set in vimrc. When I set it and set the term variable to xterm-256color I had the background colour only on the text. I then found the solution to set the term variable to screen-256color but this has only allowed for the background to fill up to the text in the file but not in the empty space below. Does anyone have a solution for this? I have attached both screenshots below:

[image: xterm-256color]

[image: screen-256color]

Comment: I'm having this trouble now with Debian in WSL and PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots, it looks like you are working on the cmd.exe application and using vim from the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) feature in Win10. Depending on which build you are currently on, you may or may not have full support for your desired colour space (outside the lines containing any characters).

Until recently, the cmd.exe only supported 16 colors. Thus, a setting of t_Co=256 (or equivalent) in vimrc means that your 256-color colorscheme shall be approximated to the nearest colour in the 16-color palette.  In Sep 2016, the developers of WSL for Win10, announced support for 24-bit truecolor leapfrogging just 256 colours. You can read about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/). However, there is no publicly accessible setting from the console properies to change the colorscheme.

As an aside, the Win10 developers have decided to replace cmd.exe with PowerShell as the **default** command-line application, although Microsoft later clarified in a blog-post that cmd.exe shall continue to be included in the OS and there are no plans of deprecating it. Powershell's default colorscheme supports only 16 bit colors. There is a feature request to enable more colours support for powershell, and you can read about it in Powershell's github issues page.

A solution for you would be to use the native windows build of Vim (available in chocolatey repos as well as from the official github pages, and a few other sources), and use gvim, which shall have no issues whatsoever in rendering 24-bit colors.